# Find most northern coordinate

Tags: javascript, openlayers

Let's say you have an array of coordinates ( lat & long ), is there a way in Javascript to determine which of these coordinates is the most northern one?

Why am I asking? In Openlayers we want to show a popup when a polygon is clicked. In most cases the user clicks somewhere & then we have 1 coordinate to use. In other cases the polygon will be automatically centered on the screen & in this case we only have the points of the polygon itself. Showing the popup on the most northern point is the best option.

Thanks in advance,
Yannick

Comment: I can't think of any circumstance where it wouldn't just be the one with the highest latitude?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just take the greatest [latitude](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latitude) value for th most north coordinate. You may have a look here as well: [Geographic coordinate system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geographic_coordinate_system).

Answer (score 0):

latitude and longitude already describe positions on a sphere in terms of north-south and east-west, respectively. You can simply loop through all the co-ordinates and pull out the highest latitude.